# Docker Compose volume not mount for mysql image

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, devops

I am trying to create a new Docker image with `docker-compose.yml` file. Here is my `docker-compose.yml` file.

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  php-fpm:
      build:
       context: ./images/php-fpm/
       dockerfile: Dockerfile
      container_name: lempdock_php-fpm_1
      volumes:
        - ./www:/var/www
      depends_on:
        - redis
        - mysql
  nginx:
      build:
        context: ./images/nginx
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      container_name: lempdock_nginx_1
      ports:
        - "80:80"
        - "443:443"
      volumes:
        - ./www:/var/www
        - ./images/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
        - ./images/nginx/sites/:/etc/nginx/sites-available
        - ./images/nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      external_links:
        - lemp_dock_nginx_1
      depends_on:
        - php-fpm
  mysql:
      build:
        context: ./images/mysql
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      container_name: lempdock_mysql_1
      restart: always
      volumes:
        - ./data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
      external_links:
        - lempdock_mysql_1
      ports:
        - "33066:3306"
      expose:
        - 3306
  redis:
      image: redis
      container_name: lempdock_redis_1
      ports:
        - "6379:6379"
      volumes:
        - ./data/redis:/data/redis
      external_links:
        - lempdock_redis_1
```

This is my folder structure

```
- /data
---- /mysql
---- /redis
- /images # contain other sub foldes with Dockerfile
- /lemp
-/www # to contain my souce code
```

As per my `docker-compose.yml` file, my `www` folder from root mounted and synced properly with `php-fpm` and `nging` docker image, but my `mysql` data not synced with `data/mysql` folder.

What I am missing here and How can I get my MySQL data folder mounted to my host computers `data/mysql` folder?

This is the Github link https://github.com/arifulhb/lempdock if anyone wants to check out this.

Comment: I ran `docker-compose up` from your repository, and mysql data files appeared in `./data/mysql` folder. What is your experience?

Comment: Hi @Yui Fedorov, which environment you run it? My `./data/mysql` folder is just empty. No data is shared from the container. I am running in Mac.

Comment: I'm running on Mac as well. Please try starting from scratch. Make a new folder somewhere, `git clone` your repo, and run `docker-compose up`. Maybe remove the PHP section as it takes too much time, just for this test.

Comment: @YuryFedorov awesome man. It works. Thanks. Add your solution in an answer and I'll accept this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `docker-compose` configuration is fine, there is no reason it wouldn't work.

There might be an issue with permissions or something similar, depending on the platform you use. If you start from scratch (`git clone`, `docker-compose up`), it should work.